# Random "spawn" of divs

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm trying to create a "spawn point" for a div.  I have made it work and I have a working collision detector for it.  There are two things I wanted to ask regarding my code.

1. How do I get my code to work with more than one player (window.i).  - At the moment, after an hour of fiddling, I've only broken my code.  This whole area screws up the collision detector, I have more than one player showing at times, but I'm unable to move.
2. How do I make it so that it detects the contact before it happens - I've tried working with the "tank's" margin and subtracting it's width, so that before it makes contact it calls an event, but it has been unsuccessful and completely stopped the collision function working.

I'm sorry that it's asking a lot, I really do understand that, but the issues come into eachother and rebound off so I thought it was best I put it all into one question rather than 2 separate ones an hour apart.

```js
function animate() {
    var tank = document.createElement("div");
    tank.id= "tank";
    tank.style.marginLeft="0px";
    tank.style.marginTop="0px";
    tank.style.height="10px";
    tank.style.width="10px";
    document.body.appendChild(tank);

    x = parseInt(tank.style.marginLeft);
    y = parseInt(tank.style.marginTop);

    document.onkeydown = function () {

        e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            if (x > 0) {
                if (collisionDetector() == false) {
                    x = x - 10;
                    tank.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
                } else {
                    alert();
                }
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            if (x < 790) {
                if (collisionDetector() == false) {
                    x = x + 10;
                    tank.style.marginLeft = x + "px";
                } else {
                    alert();
                }
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '38') {
            if (y > 0) {
                if (collisionDetector() == false) {
                    y = y - 10;
                    tank.style.marginTop = y + "px";
                } else {
                    alert();
                }
            }
        } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
            if (y < 490) {
                if (collisionDetector() == false) {
                    y = y + 10;
                    tank.style.marginTop = y + "px";
                } else {
                    alert();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
window.lives = 3;

function playerSpawn() {
window.i = 1;
while (i > 0) {
        var player = document.createElement("div");
        randMarL = Math.ceil(Math.random()*80)*10;
        randMarT = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)*10;
        player.id = "player";
        player.style.marginLeft= randMarL + "px";
        player.style.marginTop= randMarT + "px";
        player.style.height="10px";
        player.style.width="10px";
        document.body.appendChild(player);
        i--;
    }
}
function collisionDetector() {
    x1 = tank.style.marginLeft;
    x2 = player.style.marginLeft;
    y1 = tank.style.marginTop;
    y2 = player.style.marginTop;
    if ((x1 == x2 && y1 == y2)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```